# Newly appended item causes previously appended item to lose toggle functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic jQuery script that appends new divs into a UL element. Upon hitting custom "ADD TASK" button, a new div is appended to the bottom of the UL area. With each newly appended item, I would like the item to have have toggle function that displays hidden div underneath. Basically this is a to do list. I want to add a new item and have a details button you can press that will show an area underneath similar to how an accordion works. I have the script all working, the append function is incrementing newly created divs to give them unique ID. The issue is this: When I append task 1, it's collapsible, when I append task 2, task 2 is collapsible, but task 1 loses its collapsibility. Basically just having an issue making sure every appended item has functioning accordion/ details section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let i = 0;

  $('#add').on('click', () => {
    $('ul').append(
      '<div class="divvy">' +
      '<input type="text" class="inputty"/><button class="remove" id="deletestyle"> X </button>' +
      '<div class="detailcontainer" id="accordion' + i + '"> <p>DETAILS</p></div><div id="panel' + i + '">' +
      '<label for="details">Details</label><textarea name="details" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea><br><label for="date">Due Date</label><input type="date" name="date"></div></div>');

    i++;

    $('#accordion0').on('click', () => {
      $('#panel0').toggle();
    });

    $('#accordion1').on('click', () => {
      $('#panel1').toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="optionBox">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">ADD TASK</button>
    <ul id="sortable">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a common class with contextual lookups.  Don't repeat bindings with ids like id1, id2, id3.  This is a anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're nesting event handlers. On the second click of the button you've added two event handlers to the `div`, so `toggle()` is therefore clicked twice and shows then immediately hides the element again.

To fix this, and also improve the logic, remove the incremental `id` attributes and instead use a single delegated event handler based on the class you apply to the elements, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').on('click', () => {
    $('ul').append(
      '<div class="divvy">' +
      '<input type="text" class="inputty"/><button class="remove" id="deletestyle"> X </button>' +
      '<div class="detailcontainer"> <p>DETAILS</p></div><div class="panel">' +
      '<label for="details">Details</label><textarea name="details" rows="10" cols="30" ></textarea><br><label for="date">Due Date</label><input type="date" name="date"></div></div>');
  });

  $('ul').on('click', '.detailcontainer', function() {
    $(this).closest('.divvy').find('.panel').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="optionBox">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add">ADD TASK</button>
    <ul id="sortable"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, that of course did the trick. You're a genius. Thank you kindly! And thanks for the explanation it made perfect sense!!